# ContentScale not working properly in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple compose UI using Image composable. Whenever I set the little image to my composable size, the image does not crop properly and some paddings showed. My drawable size is 125x125 and my composable size is 350dp. Here is my code example:

```
Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sample_image_2),
        contentDescription = "Player Main Image",
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(350.dp)
            .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10))
            .align(CenterHorizontally)
            .padding(0.dp)
            .clickable { },
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )
```

[image]

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: What is the expected outcome, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I attach screenshoot to my question. when my drawable size smaller than imageView width and height, crop not correctly and not resize image

Answer (score 0):

Try to add fillMaxSize() in the image's modifier like this:

```
Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sample_image_2),
        contentDescription = "Player Main Image",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .size(350.dp)
            .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10))
            .align(CenterHorizontally)
            .padding(0.dp)
            .clickable { },
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
)
```

So contentScale will work!